# Create *.reg file using *.bat CMD line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

I need some help with this problem...

I want to use a `*.bat` file to create and add a `*.reg` to system. If I try manually on CMD prompt, it works. i.e:

***~~ prompt window opened ~~***

`copy con "myregister.reg"`

***~~** I paste my `*.reg` content here **~~***

***~~** I press `Ctrl+Z` **~~***

`^Z`

***~~** I press `Enter` **~~***

***~~ my register has been created ~~***

But if I try to create a `*.bat` with this content:

```
copy con "myregister.reg"
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Developer]

 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Developer\HisSoftware]

 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Developer\HisSoftware\Jumplist]
 "Recent sessions"=hex(7):41,00,66,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6d,00,61,00,72,00,6b,00,\
 ...
^Z
```

...it doesn't works.

**What can I do?**

*I'm sorry for my poor english :$*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method has some limitations with certain characters that need to be escaped with `^`

Like these: `^)` `^&` `^<` `^>` `^|`

```
@echo off
(
echo.Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
echo.
echo.[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Developer]
echo.
echo.[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Developer\HisSoftware]
echo.
echo.[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Developer\HisSoftware\Jumplist]
echo. "Recent sessions"=hex(7):41,00,66,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6d,00,61,00,72,00,6b,00,\
) >file.reg
```